# Unable to update sshd config file with Ansible

Tags: linux, unix, ansible

I have followed the solution posted on the post 
[Ansible to update sshd config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638944/ansible-to-update-sshd-config-file/54868572#54868572) however I am getting the following errors.

```
TASK [Add Group to AllowGroups] 
fatal: [testpsr]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (lineinfile) module: when Supported parameters include: attributes, backrefs, backup, content, create, delimiter, directory_mode, firstmatch, follow, force, group, insertafter, insertbefore, line, mode, owner, path, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, state, unsafe_writes, validate"}

Here are the tasks I have. 
- name: Capture AllowUsers from sshd_config 
  command: bash -c "grep '^AllowUsers' /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak" 
  register: old_userlist changed_when: no

- name: Add Group to AllowUsers 
  lineinfile: regexp: "^AllowUsers" 
  backup: True 
  dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak 
  line: "{{ old_userlist.stdout }} {{ usernames }}" 
  when: - old_userlist is succeeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you whats wrong.

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (lineinfile) module: when
```

You nested `when` under `lineinfile` module, while it should be nested under the task itself.

This is your code fixed and probably what you meant.

```
- name: Capture AllowUsers from sshd_config 
  command: "grep '^AllowUsers' /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak" 
  register: old_userlist
  changed_when: no

- name: Add Group to AllowUsers
  lineinfile: 
    regexp: "^AllowUsers"
    backup: yes
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak
    line: "{{ old_userlist.stdout }} {{ usernames }}"
  when: old_userlist is succeeded
```

I also fixed a couple of things. Using `bash -c` in `command` is redundant in your case

Please make sure you are using code formatting when pasting code or logs on StackOverflow, as your question is currently unreadable.

Comment: thanks for the edit vane41.  It did work, however, the user got added as [u 'username'].

Comment: You should take a closer look on how you define `usernames`. This should point you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521816/4794849

Comment: Thanks again for the pointer.  Change the line: to the following and it worked.line: "{{ old_grouplist.stdout }} {{ ' '.join(usernames) }}"